# How to create a duplicate of subdirectories using find

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have two subdirectories in `/home/ziga/Mounted/`. Each of those has multiple non-empty subdirectories:

```
/home/ziga/Mounted/dir1/subdir1-1
/home/ziga/Mounted/dir1/subdir1-2
...

/home/ziga/Mounted/dir2/subdir2-1
/home/ziga/Mounted/dir2/subdir2-2
...
```

Is there any way to use `find` to create **empty** directories in, say `/home/ziga/CombinedMounts` that would have exact same names as those that are two levels deep inside `/home/ziga/Mounted/`? This is the end-result I'm looking for:

```
/home/ziga/CombinedMounts/subdir1-1
/home/ziga/CombinedMounts/subdir1-2
/home/ziga/CombinedMounts/subdir2-1
/home/ziga/CombinedMounts/subdir2-2
...
```

I can get the list of directories using this command:

```
find /home/ziga/Mounted/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d ! -name "lost+found" ! -name ".Trash*" -exec basename {} \;
```

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use its output in `mkdir -p` so that I would get the desired subdirectories.

Somehow they always end up in `/home/ziga/CombinedMounts/home/ziga/Mounted/...`

I'm losing my mind, please help. :)

**NOTE**: some of the directory names contain spaces!

Comment: Could you set the results as elements of an array? Like `DIRS=(\`<your find statment>\`)`. Then use a `for dir in $DIRS` to make each directory.

Comment: Would that work if there are spaces in the directory names?

Comment: Oh, maybe not. I'm not a bash expert, just spit-balling here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
find /home/ziga/Mounted/ -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 \
  -type d ! -name "lost+found" ! -name ".Trash*" \
  -exec sh -c 'mkdir -p /home/ziga/CombinedMounts/"$(basename "$0")"' "{}" \;
```

I'll explain only the parts that you haven't mentioned in the question.

We invoked `sh` because we cannot reliably pass the `{}` placeholder to an expression like `mkdir -p "/path/$(basename "{}")"`. The expression also looks unclear with the placeholder.

The `-c` option sets the value of parameter `0` from the value of the operand after the command string (refer to the man page for `sh`):

> `-c`        Read commands from the command_string operand. Set the value of special parameter 0  (see  Section 2.5.2,  Special  Parameters) from the value of the `command_name` operand and the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, and so on) in sequence from the remaining argument operands. No  commands  shall  be read from the standard input.

Comment: Amazing! This is it! :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and especially the correct positions of all kinds of quotes and brackets ;) Those always get me mad. After banging my head for a couple of hours, you present me with the solution in a matter of minutes. Thanks again!